# What does Phalcon\Mvc\Model::findFirst((int) $id)?

Tags: model, phalcon

Does it get entity by primary key.. or just taking entity from table with specified number?

If i do smth like

```
$model = new Phalcon\Mvc\Model();
$model->findFirst('id = 1');
```

It's clear. But if i define

```
$model->findFirst(1);
```

What it should return? Entity with primary key="1" or first entity from table? I'm asking because i've found in my team's code methods such

```
class BaseModel extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{
     public function getById($id) { /* ... */ }
}
```

And i am not sure that we really need them.

Second question - if when we execute findFirst($int), and it returns entity by primary key, is it properly escaped?

P.S. According to https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/265 it should return entity by primary key, right?

Comment: Can you instantiate Phalcon\Mvc\Model?

Comment: I wrote new Phalcon\Mvc\Model() as example, i always use extended classes with defined methods getSource(), etc, if it is your question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you pass only an integer number to the findFirst method it will check if the mapped model has just one primary key field and then it'll perform query like this:

```
Products::findFirst(1); //SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = 1
```

What is the same as:

```
Products::findFirst("id = 1");
```

The (int) parameter only works if the first parameter is an integer valid value, the safe way to do this with external data is:

```
Products::findFirst([
    "id = ?0",
    "bind" => [$externalId]
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

findFirst(55) will return the first record with primary key's first found field equal with 55.
Although i don't think its a good ideea, this can be used when you have 2 or more fields as the primary key because it adds LIMIT 1 to the actual query, as using find(55) doesn't.

Contrary of what i believed once, it doesn't use the primary key index order to "choose"
the first field to use. It uses the order in which the fields are found in the table.

So if you have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE `T` (
    `A` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
    `B` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`A`, `B`)
);
```

findFirst(66) will produce this query:

```
SELECT ... WHERE `T`.`B` = 66 LIMIT 1
```

If you want to confirm, use events manager to log the exact queries.
( http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/events.html#usage-example )

Also findFirst($var) will not escape $var, so if somehow $var = "55 OR 1=1" the actual query will be:
SELECT (...) WHERE 55 OR 1 = 1 LIMIT 1